# Stylization in array C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I created the array like a gameboard for Tic-Tac-Toe but I can't figure out how to solve problem with stylization. It's fine in first 2 lines but in the last one, it doesn't have space between each element how it should has.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProjectTicTacToe
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   A B C");
            Console.WriteLine();

            string[,] deska = new string[,] {
                { "1  ", "2  ", "3  " },
                { "0 ", "0 ", "0" },
                { "0 ", "0 ", "0" },
                { "0 ", "0 ", "0" },
            };

            for (int j = 0; j < deska.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < deska.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(deska[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

How it look's like:
[screenshot http://upnisito.cz/images/2017_01/648array.png](http://upnisito.cz/images/2017_01/648array.png)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Reverse `deska[i, j]` to `deska[j, i]`.

Comment: Your data is transposed which can make traversal and alignment awkward. Had you gone traversing by row, you'd see that the last set if `0`s do not contain the space the others do.

Comment: Thank you! Please, do you know how to change how I print the data? Like now the first row should be 1  2  3 etc... ? When I switch i and j in for loop it shows me error that index is out of array's borders... thank you :)

Comment: Put the "1 " "2 " and "3 " on the left, instead of at the top :)

Comment: @AlešWilk when you use the GetLength method it returns the length value of that dimension for your multidimensional array. Your vales for this would be 3 and 4. In your for loop you need to subtract 1 from that as you have it setup to loop based on index number. and GetLength counting starts at 1 not 0. 

So when you ran your code it still errors but after you get your grid print out, when you switched it errored before it had a chance to print one row. So either way you you look at it you have to subtract 1 in both for loops.

Comment: @AlešWilk It's good decorum to select an answer that is in line with helping your solve your question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to pre-format your layout inside the strings themselves, let the program do that for you.

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,8}{1,3}{2,3}","A","B","C"));
Console.WriteLine();
string[,] deska = new string[,] {
    { "1", "2", "3" },
    { "0", "0", "0" },
    { "0", "0", "0" },
    { "0", "0", "0" },
};

for (int j = 0; j < deska.GetLength(1)-1 ; j++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-5}{1,3}{2,3}{3,3}",deska[0,j],deska[1,j],deska[2,j],deska[3,j]));
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I have never seen the alignment stuff used in string.format before. Today I have learnt something new. thank you. :)

Comment: I had only previously used in with numbers, but knowing it could pad empty space to align rows of numbers, I figured so just googled it for this.

Answer (score 1):

Or try declare your array like this for quick fix:

```
  string[,] deska = {
            { "1  ", "2  ", "3  " },
            { "0 ", "0 ", "0 " },
            { "0 ", "0 ", "0 " },
            { "0 ", "0 ", "0 " }
        };
```

Update: Also in C# you have a lot of flexibility to manage console output, see little example below. It's not a general solution, but you can do this as you wish better.

```
using System;

namespace ProjectTicTacToe
{
  internal class Program
  {
    private static void Main()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("   A B C");
      Console.WriteLine();

      string[,] deska =
            {
                { "1 ", "2 ", "3 " },
                { "0 ", "0 ", "0" },
                { "0 ", "0 ", "0" },
                { "0 ", "0 ", "0" },
            };

      int prevLenght = 0;
      int currentLenght = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < deska.GetLength(0); i++)
      {
        currentLenght += prevLenght;
        for (int j = 0; j < deska.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
          Console.SetCursorPosition(currentLenght, Console.CursorTop);
          prevLenght = deska[i, j].Length + 1;
          Console.WriteLine(deska[i, j]);
        }

        Console.CursorTop -= deska.GetLength(1);
      }
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```